# My primary key is not getting updated

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, datagridview

When I tried to update my primary key from the textbox, it's not getting updated. The rest of the columns are updated fine. Please help me.

I am not getting any error. Nothing.. When I try to update the part number.. it's not updating.. Simply going back to the previous value.

My code to update value to database:

```
private void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SREEJITHMOHA492\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=cndb;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"update cncinfo set part='" + this.file_NameTextBox.Text 
        + "',drawings='" + this.drawingsTextBox.Text + "',draftpath='"
        + this.gcodeTextBox.Text + "',comments='" + this.commentsTextBox.Text
        + "' where part='" + dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'  ;", con);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

void load_table()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SREEJITHMOHA492\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=cndb;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select part as 'Part Number',drawings as 'Drawings',draftpath as 'G-Code Path',releasepath as 'Release Path',comments as 'Comments' from cncinfo ;", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    try
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        dbddataset = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dbddataset);

        BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
        bSource.DataSource = dbddataset;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
        sda.Update(dbddataset);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/). And if the `set` and `where` clauses both use `file_NameTextBox.Text` for the `part` column, how are you going to change the value? If you check the value returned by `ExecuteNonQuery` you'll likely find it's zero when you try to change a part name because no rows are updated.

Comment: Well if you use `SqlCommand Parameters` it will be easy to figure out the issue. Seems like you are not updating `Part Number` column. Also as @HABO said, `ExecuteNonQuery` is not supposed to be used with `Select` query.

Comment: Please guy just give me a code help. I am buging this for last two days. I tried so many days.. No way!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use parameters.  See [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Second, your `update` statement uses the same input for both the `set` and `where` clauses:

@"update cncinfo set part='" + **this.file_NameTextBox.Text** + "',...' where part='" + **this.file_NameTextBox.Text** + "'  ;"

How do you plan to change the value of the `part` when you select only the row that *already* has the new value? You need to use both an old and new value:

@"update cncinfo set part='" + **this.file_NameTextBox.Text** + "',...' where part='" + **oldPart** + "'  ;"

Finally, `ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of rows affected. If you checked the value you would find that it is `1` when you update a row and `0` when you try to change the value of `part` unless there is already a row with the new `part` value (in which case you update that row instead of generating an error on a duplicate part).

You should also consider using a [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) for your connections and commands.

Comment: i made it to `SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SREEJITHMOHA492\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=cndb;Integrated Security=True");
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"update cncinfo set part='" + this.file_NameTextBox.Text 
                    + "',drawings='" + this.drawingsTextBox.Text + "',draftpath='"
                    + this.gcodeTextBox.Text + "',comments='" + this.commentsTextBox.Text
                    + "' where part='" + dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'  ;", con);` this time its chaning only first row.

Comment: I assume when you tell it to update the database row corresponding to `dataGridView1.Rows[0]` that you expect it to always update the "first" row. You wouldn't specify `0` if you didn't mean it.

Comment: Does the user pick a row to edit, or do they just type in some suggested values to drop on the existing table? If they pick a row then you could save the `col[0]` value in a variable, e.g. `oldPart`, just about the same time that you copy it to `file_NameTextBox` so that you'll know what it was before it changed to something else.

Comment: i did `dataGridView1.Column[0].Value.ToString()`  this too brother.. its showing column is not contained the context

Comment: You seem to be lacking some fairly fundamental understanding of the tools you are trying to use: C#, .NET, SQL, debugger, ... . I'm afraid that this is going to be your fifth question on SO that doesn't result in an acceptable answer since you are expecting a considerable amount of hand holding to lead you through coding your application.